# Criar gráficos com dados de uma planilha diferente e número de colunas variado

Tags: excel-vba, gráfico

Preciso gerar um gráfico para  cada linha de uma base de dados. Essa base de dados varia tanto em número de colunas como em número de linhas, e está em uma planilha diferente, chanada Matriz 1.
Sempre que rodo meu código está dando um erro no SetSourceData, e não consigo identificar oq está acontecendo.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?
Segue meu código.

```
Sub createColumnChartMatriz12()

Dim ChartName As String
Dim Row As Integer
Dim ChartRow As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Matriz 1")
Dim k As Long
Dim z As Long

k = sh.Range("A1", 
sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Coun
z = sh.Cells(1, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 4
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Matriz1Chart").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.RowHeight = 15.5
Cells(1, 1).Select


ChartRow = 49
Row = 2
For Row = 2 To k

ChartName = "Utilização no Período " & sh.Cells(Row, 1).Value

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select

With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=sh.Range(Cells(Row, 4), Cells(Row, z)), _
            PlotBy:=xlRows
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Matriz 1'!$D$1:$AM$1"
    .Parent.Height = Range("A1:A15").Height
    .Parent.Width = Range("A1:J1").Width
    .Parent.Top = Range("A" & ChartRow).Top
    .Parent.Left = Range("A" & ChartRow).Left
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = ChartName
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Meses"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Utilização"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mm-yyyy"
End With

ChartRow = ChartRow + 16

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Consegue criar um [mcve]? com os dados [da tabela](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) em que isso ocorre?

Comment: Tente `.SetSourceData Source:=sh.Range(sh.Cells(Row, 4), sh.Cells(Row, z)), _
            PlotBy:=xlRows`